# RelativeLayout with ImageView and TextView - Align TextView below ImageView, both center in RelativeLayout Programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout with ImageView and TextView. I want to the TextView right below the ImageView(with a small padding) and both the ImageView and TextView, aligned to center in the RelativeLayout.

**The RelativeLayout is added Programatically**

I have read some questions on SO regarding the alignment, but, I can't get them to work for me. Below is my current code...

Code for RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

Code for ImageView

```
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);  
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpImage = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lpImage.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        //Setting the parameters on the Image
        image.setLayoutParams(lpImage);

        //adding imageview to relative layout
        relativeLayout.addView(image);
```

Code for TextView

```
TextView textview = new TextView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpTextView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lpTextView.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, image.getId());

            //Setting the parameters on the TextView
            textview.setLayoutParams(lpTextView);

            //Adding TextView to relative layout
            relativeLayout.addView(textview);
```

If I set `RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT` for both image and text, they overlap eachother, which is understandable as RelativeLayout supports overlapping of views.

I thought setting `RelativeLayout.BELOW` for textview will make it align itself below the image, but it's not the case. I even tried `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM`for textview, but even that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this..

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprela = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lprela);

ImageView image = new ImageView(this);  
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpImage = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lpImage.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    //Setting the parameters on the Image
    image.setLayoutParams(lpImage);

    //adding imageview to relative layout
    relativeLayout.addView(image);

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpTextView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpTextView.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, image.getId());

        //Setting the parameters on the TextView
        textview.setLayoutParams(lpTextView);

        //Adding TextView to relative layout
        relativeLayout.addView(textview);
```

Or

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_ineer_ver = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);

ImageView image = new ImageView(this);  
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpImage = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //Setting the parameters on the Image
        image.setLayoutParams(lpImage);

        //adding imageview to relative layout
        linearLayout.addView(image);

TextView textview = new TextView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpTextView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            //Setting the parameters on the TextView
            textview.setLayoutParams(lpTextView);

            //Adding TextView to relative layout
            linearLayout.addView(textview);
```

Comment: I got it to work using LinearLayout method. Thanks for the answer. But, there is a small change.. Instead of using Gravity.CENTER in layoutparams, using, linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) worked for me. Please change your answer accordingly. Thanks.. Answer Accepted.

Comment: @Hariharan Thank you to share your code but i am facing one problem, text are moved in the center when there is no image.

Comment: @Rstar just remove `linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` from parent `LinearLayout` and try.

Answer (score 0):

Below process may also work for you.
1) Add Image view & Text view in vertical LinearLayout.
2) Add the linear layout to Center of Relative layout.(using CENTER_IN_PARENT).